# What is the area-decreasing 'convex hull'?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

Let $K \subset \mathbf{R}^3$ be a compact set.

> What is the smallest set $C$ containing $K$, with the property that in a neighbourhood of $C$, the closest-point projection of surfaces onto $C$ decreases area?

- I *think* that it exists: a proof via Zorn's lemma seems conceivable.
- If $K$ is convex, then $C = K$. In general, $C$ would be a subset of the convex hull of $K$.

Comment: Do you want to say "the closest-point projection", or "there is a projection"?

Comment: @AntonPetrunin I meant the closest-point projection. Thanks for pointing this out, I've now fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt that it exists; let me explain why.

Consider a surface $\Sigma$ of lest area that surrounds $K$.
It $\Sigma$ might contain a piece $\Omega$ of generic minimal surface.
Note that that projection from equidistant piece to $\Omega$ is not area-decreasing so the body bounded by $\Sigma$ does not meet your condition.

On the other hand, it seems possible to approximate $\Sigma$ from outside by strictly mean-curvature-convex surfaces $\Sigma_n$.
So the bodies bounded by $\Sigma_n$ satisfy the condition.

Comment: I'm not quite convinced... Why is the projection onto an area-minimizing surface not area-decreasing? Also, I don't think that $\Sigma_n$ being strictly mean-convex is sufficient to ensure the area-decreasing property. (Picture for example a strictly mean-convex body around two horizontal disks lying a distance $\delta > 0$ apart - the area-minimizing catenoid sees its area increase when projected onto this.)

Comment: First part is done by computations --- if principle curvatures do not vanish then projection increases the area of equidistant surface. But, if the surface is strictly mean-curvature-convex, then the projection of a small nbhd is area-decreasing --- again, by a straightforward computations.